# Close subscription on condition with takeUntil()

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6, ngrx-store

I have a subscription to get providers from a NgRx reducer. I want to use `takeUntil()` to automatically close the subscription when is finally returns an array that has content:

```
// Fetch providers
this.store.pipe(select(reducer.getProviders))
//  .takeUntil(reducer.getProviders.length > 0)
    .subscribe(providers => {
        if (providers) {
            this.providers = providers;
//          takeUntil(/** something **/);
        }
    });
```

Can someone help me with this?

I can't figure out how to make use of `takeUntil()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`takeUntil` accepts an Observable. (Source: [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html)). For your case, it would make more sense to use `takeWhile`, this will emit values as long as a particular condition is satisfied (Source: [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html)). Set the optional `inclusive` property to true so that it will also emit the first item that didn't pass the predicate.

```js
this.store.pipe(select(reducer.getProviders))
    .takeWhile(reducer => reducer.getProviders.length == 0, true)
    .subscribe(providers => {
        if (providers) {
            this.providers = providers;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Both are correct. But, you had a code snippet XD
I did it like this: `.takeWhile(providers => providers.length === 0 || (this.providers && this.providers.length === 0))` to make sure that `providers` gets stored into `this.providers`. It works! Many thanks to @nash11 and @xdecdec

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `takeWhile()`.

`takeUntil()`'s parameter is an observable, and once that observable emits it will stop taking values.

`takeWhile()`'s parameter is a predicate which determines whether to take values.

See the documentation for takeWhile on learn-rxjs:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile

> takeWhile(predicate: function(value, index): boolean, inclusive?: boolean):
> Observable

> Emit values until provided expression is false.